# Morphia multi field sort not working for phone book-like sorting

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have a simple document like this:

```
@Entity("users")
@Indexes(@Index(fields = {@Field("lastName"), @Field("firstName")}))
public class User extends Model {
  @Indexed public String email;
  public String firstName;
  @Indexed public String lastName;
  public String employer;
}
```

Then there is a search function to find entries either on name (first/last) and/or employer.

The goal is to sort the results by last name then first name, entirely like how a phone book is presented.

My search query looks like:

```
q.field("employer").containsIgnoreCase(input);
q.order("lastName,firstName");
q.limit(25);
q.offset(start);
```

Now what's happening is the results are being sorted by the first field specified in the `q.order()` line, but what's not happening is sorting on the `lastName` and `firstName`.

As i understand sorting on multiple columns, there needs to be a compound index, which i do have defined for this collection. So i'm just at a miss as to what i'm missing.

Comment: What is the type of `q`? Where is the ascending/descending order specified? Have you read [this](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/?com/mongodb/client/model/Sorts.html)?

Comment: @saeedgnu q is a query object per: http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.0/guides/querying/#field - if you look at the code i posted, you will see: q.order("lastName, firstName"); this is per Mrophia's javadoc.

Comment: I suggest opening an issue at [morphia's github](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues)

Comment: (The sorting syntax is different from MongoDB's builtin syntax)

Comment: @saeedgnu yes i understand the syntax is different, the syntax i am using is per Morphia's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I use Datastore Morphia class and the sorting works perfect

```
        List<Page> result = datastore.find(Page.class)
            .field("isFeatured").equal(true)
            .order("parseDate, parsePriority").limit(limit).asList();
```